# ¿Por qué const {variable} = Array de ObjectId me devuelve null o undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tengo un **array** con ObjectId's de mongoose e intento crear un campo para un **JSON** para luego actualizar un documento de la base de datos `Mongo`.

Esto me devuelve nulo:

```
const { members } = JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers);
```

Y esto que es diferente de lo anterior porque deja los **ObjectId** como objetos, a diferencia del anterior que me los devuelve como cadenas para el formato **JSON**:

```
const { members } = objectIdMembers;
```

Pero es igualmente null o undefined...
¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces

```
const { members } = JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers);
```

es equivalente a

```
const members = JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers).members
```

### Caso 1

En el primer caso que mencionas

```
const { members } = JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers);
```

No tiene sentido porque `JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers)` es un String y no puedes hacer `JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers).members`

### Caso 2

En el segundo caso que mencionas

```
const { members } = objectIdMembers;
```

Funciona **sólo** si existe `objectIdMembers.members`, de lo contrario es `undefined`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, muy informativa. Tiene sentido con lo que acabo de probar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas haciendo es una destructuración.
Se utiliza cuando se esta buscando una relación un relación entre el parámetro de la variable = y el contenido con el que se iguala.

```
/*
* Esto es de cabeza
*/

export let cosa1="alguna cadena";
/*
 * cuando lo importas en la clase 
 * donde va ser usada se podría 
 * hacer de 2 maneras.
 */
import { cosa1} from 'src/app/config/config';

public cosa = cosa1;

// o

let {cosa1} = "un objeto que contenga cosa1";
```

Lo primero que haría es comprobar que valor hay en la variable (objectIdMembers) antes de hacer nada, si tiene valor asigna de manera normal

```
let/const members = JSON.stringify(objectIdMembers);
```

Comprueba que tenga valor y desde aquí, podrás hacer encode de nuevo o separas cada campo que necesites antes y organizarte lo como mas te convenga. No se si te ayudado. Pero espero que te sirva, un saludo.